# How get html of current page?

Tags: asp.net

I want parse the html of current page.
How can I get the html of current page for that in asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**for client side**

In Internet explorer

Right click on the browser --> View source

IN firefox

Right click on the browser --> View Page Source

**for server side**

You can override the page's render method to capture the HTML source on the server-side.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // setup a TextWriter to capture the markup
    TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    // render the markup into our surrogate TextWriter
    base.Render(htw);

    // get the captured markup as a string
    string pageSource = tw.ToString();

    // render the markup into the output stream verbatim
    writer.Write(pageSource);

    // remove the viewstate field from the captured markup
    string viewStateRemoved = Regex.Replace(pageSource,
        "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\".*?\" />",
        "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // the page source, without the viewstate field, is in viewStateRemoved
    // do what you like with it
}
```

Comment: you missed server-client - HttpRequest and HttpResponse

Comment: included in the second run :)

Answer (score 2):

Override Render method and call base.Render with you own HtmlWriter.

Comment: Is there a way to get html of current page using Request.Url?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* want to parse HTML? It's a tricky business. If you don't absolutely have to do it, I'd avoid it by using [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) methods client-side (if a client-side solution is acceptable).  If you're doing a *lot* of it, you might consider [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or some other tool to help.